# How to find the x and y co-ordinates for mouse hover function in karate

Tags: karate

I want to hover on the URL bar to get the exit pop up. I would like to use mouse().move() function.
Can someone please let me know how to fetch the x and y co-ordinates in karate scripting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any browser-automation-framework allows you to do this (go beyond the boundaries of the HTML viewport) so the best option is you do some research into it or wait for someone else who may have a better answer. My suggestion is don't depend on such extreme things in your scripts, they will be hard to maintain, flaky and not cross-browser compatible. They are not worth it.

That said there is a somewhat experimental "karate-robot" project that can give you full control over the mouse, so you can experiment with that: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot